# Getting string from label visible at runtime

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode

I want to get the string which is visible at my label and having line break mode .byClipping .
My real string is :-
 "This way your API interface will be nice and pretty, you’re not exposing the internals of your class to the world. If you have constants that are used in lots of classes all over the app then it makes sense to have a separate .h and .m file just for defining these constants."

but at run time i am getting :-
"This way your API interface will be nice and pretty, you’re not exposing the internals of your class to the world. If you have constants"

i want to get the below string in a variable at runtime.

Comment: Also please share a screenshot of the output you are getting.

Comment: are you unable to get whole string like this
let myString = yourLable.text
?

Comment: label.text should work. lineBreakMode is just for display purpose. make sure your are setting proper text on label.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is natively doable. The closest idea I have is to test the string size and removing/adding characters. Check if the following works for you:

```
func findTextActuallyVisibleInLabel(_ label: UILabel) -> String? {
    guard let originalText = label.text else { return nil }
    var text = originalText

    let labelSize = label.bounds
    guard labelSize.height > 0 else { return text }

    let bounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: labelSize.width, height: CGFloat.infinity)

    while !text.isEmpty && label.textRect(forBounds: bounds, limitedToNumberOfLines: label.numberOfLines).height > labelSize.height {
        text.removeLast()
        label.text = text
    }
    label.text = originalText

    return text
}
```

This seems to do its job in my case more or less. If I use wrapping that ends text with `...` the result is incorrect.
Also some optimization may be nice; currently I just use the full string and start subtracting character by character. Maybe a bisection would be nicer here.

I do still use original label so it should take all possible parameters into account like wrapping, font size, lines... I modify the actual text on the label which is then reset to original.

Possibly view animations should be disabled while this operation is in progress.